# sed replace two open brackets with a single one

Tags: sed

I have a file containing lines like

```
echo ((hello world))
```

I want the output to be

```
 echo (hello world)
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this with sed?

```
sed  's/echo \(\(/echo \(\/' myfile
```

> sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unterminated `s' command

Comment: `sed '/^echo/{s/((/(/g;s/))/)/g;}'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally escaped the delimiter:

```
sed 's/echo \(\(/echo \(\/' myfile
                        ^
```

I see you're not using `sed -E`, so it's better thet you drop all slashes as in BRE, brackets and braces shouldn't be escaped, as opposed to ERE. So the correct command would be (either of the two):

```
sed    's/echo ((/echo (/'    myfile
sed -E 's/echo \(\(/echo \(/' myfile
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out but i have an error like sed: -e expression #1, char 22: Unmatched ( or \(